# How to access Perl hash defined as a constant

Tags: perl, constants

If I define a Perl hash as a constant, like:

```
use constant SITES => {foo => 1, bar => 2};
```

how do I retrieve the values for foo and bar?  $SITES{foo} does not work.

Comment: `{foo => 1, bar => 2}` is a hash *reference*

Comment: ... it is a reference to a **non-constant** hash. For instance, you can do `SITES->{foo} = 27` without it triggering an exception or error.

Comment: If you're serious about a non-modifiable hash, you should look into `Readonly`, `Const::Fast`, or the like.  `use constant` is the wrong tool for that particular job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my $site_foo = SITES->{foo};
my $site_bar = SITES->{bar};
```

`SITES` is essentially a subroutine that returns a hash reference.

Comment: My understanding is that the Perl interpreter may inline constant subroutines, such as those generated by the `constant` pragma, hence my ever-so-slight qualification.

Comment: It does, but the sub still exists, even if in practice it's rarely actually called because calls to it have been optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a constant so no need to use $ infront of the variable and value is hash reference not just hash so HASH{'key'} would not work.
use instead `SITE->{'foo'}`